How to specify path in import_module function to dynamically import modules?
I have a class that should dynamically import a module depending on a parameter passed to the class's constructor. I'm doing this by using a dictionary where the keys are the possible parameter values, and the values are importlib.import_module functions.
In this function, I cannot figure out how to get the module name and the package name to agree with each other and work properly. Here's my file structure:
Certificate Analyst/
    CertificateAnalyst.py
    main.py
    States/
        arizona.py

The CertificateAnalyst.py file contains the class that contains the dictionary with the import statements. In main.py I run a tkinter GUI that imports the CertificateAnalyst class when submitted.
Here's what the dictionary in the class looks like:
switch = {
    'Arizona': importlib.import_module('.States.arizona', package='Certificate Analyst')
}

From my understanding, this should look in the Certificate Analyst folder for the arizona module inside the States folder. I've checked sys.path to make sure this folder is being searched. I've tried rearranging where I put the States part of the path, but this seems to be the proper way to call this. I've also tried Certificate_Analyst in place of Certificate Analyst. The error I get says No module named 'Certificate Analyst'.
What am I doing wrong here?

One thing for sure, typically package names do not contain whitespaces. Also, by the looks of things, you are missing __init__.py

@rasjani thanks for the advice. I changed my package name and added the __init__.py file. It seems python is still not recognizing this directory as a package. I tried using pkgutil to print out all packages and this one did not come up. Cannot determine what else could be the problem
